# merge multiple pdf files into one using QuestPDF in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf-generation, quest, pdfmerger

We have created the WinForm application and for PDF generate we have used QuestPDF, but now we want to merge all PDF files into one single PDF using QuestPDF.

Is there any way to merge PDF files using QuestPDF?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Currently No</strike>

It was slated for end of 2022.
However you need to watch for when the Open PR <strike>is</strike> **WAS** merged

https://github.com/QuestPDF/QuestPDF/pull/367

**LATER EDIT** this seems to now be available (untested by me)

> The Merge Documents API is now available in the 2023.6.0 release!

Comment: Anyone know if this has been implemented yet?  I see where you can merge new documents, but not an existing PDF

Comment: Ok, that's unfortunate.  Looks like it would be great for that though.